# ASP.NET Core MVC with WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-core-mvc

Currently we have an ASP.NET MVC 5 website hosted in IIS. This MVC application also contains a WCF service (.svc), which is also hosted in IIS.
The advantage is that we can use the same logic/services for the ASP.NET MVC website as for the WCF service.
(see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-iis )

Now there seems to be a move from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET **Core** MVC.

Question: is it still possible to host a WCF service in an ASP.NET **Core** MVC application, similar as what I've described above or should you stick with ASP.NET MVC 5 + WCF?

Comment: Regarding "_Now there seems to be a move from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core MVC_"... You should start new Projects with ASP.NET Core but for existing applications, you should thoroughly weigh out, it's not a straight forward migration and you'll probably run into many other pitfalls beside this, making this a quite expensive undertake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem possible to host a wcf service inside asp.net core mvc application directly. asp.net core mvc is still limited and under development. 
Best way seems to still stick with asp.net mvc 5...

**Update**: github tracking info: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3139#issuecomment-417101129